# How do I space correctly y axis which is a date vector in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a following data frame, called `st_data`:

[image]

I am interested in drawing `value` vs `year` plot, for each `person`. So following code generates a graph:

```
ggplot(st_data, aes(x = year, y = value)) 
+ geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = person), position = "dodge") 
+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

Graph:

[image]

However, as you can see, it also considered `year` axis in decimals. So I realized, as its a `int` values, may be thats why. So I converted year column to `Date` type by following:

```
st_data$year<- as.Date(as.character(st_data$year), format('%Y'))
```

It also introduced a default month and date also. So year `2008` changed to `28-05-2008`. Now the same code gave following graph:

[image]

Better than earlier, however the `year` vector has only 4 possible values viz. 1999, 2002, 2005, and 2008. So I want only these 4 years on the x-axis. How to achieve this?

I have also used `scale_x_date`, but no luck.

```
ggplot(st_data, aes(x = year, y = value)) 
+ geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = person), position = "dodge") 
+ scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y"))
```

It generates same graph as earlier one. So how do I get only 4 years on x-axis and they should be any possible values of year vector viz. 1999, 2002, 2005, and 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you don't really want to treat your year values as years. You want to treat them like a categorical variable. So don't do the `st_data$year=as.Date` stuff. But make sure `year` is a factor

```
#sample data
st_data <- data.frame(
    person=factor(rep(c("06037","24510"), each=4)),
    year=rep(c(1999,2002,2005,2008), 2),
    value=c(runif(4,1000,2000), runif(4, 0,500))
)

#convert year to factor
st_data$year = factor(st_data$year)
```

Just use

```
ggplot(st_data, aes(x = year, y = value)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = person), position = "dodge")
```

to get

[image: sample bar plot]

Comment: when I ran the same sample set you gave, I got the correct graph. But with my sample data, I am getting same as http://i.stack.imgur.com/aSRG5.png What could be the problem?

Comment: @avi oops, i forgot to make it clear that `year` should be a factor. I will edit.